# How to replace a synchronized block that uses a mutex with a reentrantlock

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

To get the most benefit from the new [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) feature in Java 21+, it is suggested to replace `synchronized` blocks / functions with [reentrant locks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

This is easy in many cases:

```
public synchronized int size() {
    return map.size();
}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public int size() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        return map.size();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

What about a case where we pass a mutex in?

```
public int size() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        return c.size();
    }
}
```

In this case, can we wrap the whole synchronized block in a reentrant lock? Will the following pin the reentrant lock instead of the OS thread? If not, how do we best handle this situation?

```
private final Object mutex;
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public MyClass(Object mutex) {
    this.mutex = mutex;
}

public int size() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return c.size();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have 2 locks like that in the last example?

Comment: As per [this article](https://neiljbrown.com/2022/07/23/preparing-for-java-virtual-threads/) "*If the code that’s executing is short lived / runs fast, then this isn’t an issue – no changes to your code are needed*". So if you're just calling `size` on a (presumably non-thread-safe) Map, that's a constant-time, non-blocking operation anyway.

Comment: You need to **replace** the mutex (if you really need to), and not just **add** another form of mutual exclusion. And thread pinning with `synchronized` is largely a problem with blocking operations, so if there is no blocking operation, or not a heavily contended monitor, then **replacing** `synchronized` with `ReentrantLock` is unlikely to provide much benefit.

Comment: @Michael I missed that. Thanks. I thought all synchronized blocks should be replaced so this greatly reduced the scope!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Much appreciated! I understand now that I can forgo the refactor for anything that's short lived and not blocking.